# How to change Wordpress content when accessing using a specific URL

Tags: android, wordpress, mobile, webview

I have a Wordpress webpage working great, now I've been asked to develop an Android application with a simple web view that would load the webpage but when using the app it have to change some web behaviors.

Usually you go to the Home, and you have categories like: Services, last deals, projects...
The idea when using the app is going direct to the login page and change the menú categories, so some pages would be hidden and another ones would appear.

I've seen the @media way to do it, but I don't want to apply all these changes by resolution, but for type of device.

I checked this out: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/ but then when I redirect to the custom URL and I do the changes, I don't know how to preserve them, while navigating to other pages.

Is there any way of preserving that "mobile session"? or would it be a good choice to create a sub domine and replicate the webpage for mobile? (www.mobile.webpage.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your situation and the best idea would be to generate screens using your own code. IN order to get the data from WordPress, you can call **WP-Rest** handles to get the data.

Alternatively if you only want to load webview, your web team will need to do custom code in order to facilitate your request. **The idea is to send query variables to the website when calling from mobile app**. Once the url is called, the WP code needs to set up transient/session/cookie and display custom result if transient/session/cookie is set.

I am sorry, I can't find the exact code that I used for somewhat similar work but if your web team has ever dealt with transient or custom session, they should be able to do this without any issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking of. I'll give a try! Thank you!

Comment: Good luck mate!!